# after postback bootstrap font size changing (increasing)

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

After searching 2 hours continuously i didn't getting answer
I am developing web application in asp.net but 
after postback bootstrap font size changing (increasing)

```
when loading first time page
    body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    after post back


    scaffolding.less:31
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

as look same CSS but change in view
Is there any solution......
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You're CSS is getting overwritten by something... Use the Chrome development tools and inspect the element... It should tell you what's causing your CSS to be overwritten...

Also, try this as a long shot:

```
  body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

The `!important` rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the `!important` property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

Comment: it uses some time ` input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}` @Thomas Withers

Comment: Did you try using !important ? You just need to ensure that the style is overwritten by your code... If this doesn't work let me know and we can try some JavaScript @DHANANJAY

Comment: Ok i will try & let you know @Thomas Withers

Comment: Yeah !important works in Mozila @Thomas Withers **Thanks...**

Comment: Hey, That's great @DHANANJAY Please upvote and mark correct for the next person who has the issue!!

Comment: @DHANANJAY Clear your chrome cache or try incognito and that should work fine

Comment: Yes that also i have done but after hosting on another system browser it happens @Thomas Withers

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `alert()` for post back it may cause problem try something else than `alert()`. this problem is cause by VB

Comment: But instead of alert what can be indicate(prompt) to the client....@darshan ruikar

Comment: Yes I am using alert after postback but I also want to use alert box @darshanruikar